# get Id out of an array and toggle it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loops, dom

I am trying to build an "auto toggle". My plan was it to do it with an loop. The `array[i].onclick` works so far but I can't get further to the toggle animation.

```
function setContentBox() {
  for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function() {
      var x = document.getElementById(textWord[i] + "commentB");
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setContentBox();
});
```

```html
<div class="translaterBox">
  <span ng-repeat="text in textWords track by $index" id="{{text}}" class="container">
    {{text + " "}}
    <div id="{{text + 'commentB'}}" class="comment-box">
      <h4 class="title">{{text}}</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `id` use common `class` and use  `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic here is a *lot* more complicated than it needs to be. As you're already using jQuery you can simply use classes on the repeated elements to identify them, then use DOM traversal within the click handler to find and amend the related elements. Try this:

```html
<div class="translaterBox">
  <span ng-repeat="text in textWords track by $index" id="{{text}}" class="container">
    {{text + " "}}
    <div id="{{text + 'commentB'}}" class="comment-box">
      <h4 class="title">{{text}}</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.comment-box').toggle();
  });
});
```